# Underlying issue in a question was due to a typo. Think I should delete, but when I click "delete" it warns me about possibly of ban

Tags: discussion

I asked a [CSS Flexbox question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273772/), and the underlying issue was that I had a `.` (class selector) where I needed a `#` (ID selector). In other words, it was an embarrassingly simple typo issue, nothing more.

I think this is a question that deserves deletion, and I clicked "delete" but I was warned:

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account
>   being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

Should I delete the question anyway? Is there the possibility of penalty if I do so?

Comment: You should instead vote to close the question because it was caused by "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete it anyway since it has an upvoted/accepted answer. In this case, honestly, I wouldn't worry about keeping the question up. It doesn't cost us anything to keep it around and nobody gains much by deleting it.

That being said, *in general*, yes, there is a possibility of a penalty for people who delete a lot of their questions, assuming a number of other criteria are met as well. I can't reveal exactly what goes into a question block, but I can tell you that you personally are not in any danger. :)

This warning is designed to teach users who are habitually posting questions and deleting them as soon as they're answered, effectively abusing Stack Overflow for quick answers that only they benefit from. Most people who just use the site in normal ways should have nothing to worry about here.